# How do create a clickable URL from mysql php result on same page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Ok so I have a search page, that is able to retrieve from a database. It displays everything "on the same page", by using php, javascript, css. I am using XMLHttpRequest to send form data (a input text) to the php, which will return the results nicely.

Now the results are there, but I want to be able to click a result and then it must open another overlay and show the extended details of that ONE result.

How do I make a search result page, that when I click on the result, will feed the unique values into display.php, then open the overlay and there display the necessary results of that link (ALL ON THE SAME PAGE, NO RELOAD, NO REDIRECT). If I write it like so :

```
echo "<a id='",$row['compuid']," onlclick='soverlay();roverlay()' href='#'>",$row['compn']," | ",$row['compt']," </a>";
```

then I cant seem to link the unique generated id to :

```
document.getElementById("???compuid???").value;
```

Comment: post codes only relevant to what you are asking. these are gazillion lines of codes. i tell you no one would read all of that

Comment: someone mentioned to show code, so that's just what I did

Comment: removed the main codes ...

Comment: `by using php, java, css` Java != Javascript.

Comment: Where are you using `document.getElementById("???compuid???").value;`? Is it inside `soverlay()` or `roverlay()`? You might be able to use `this.value`, although you don't have a `value` attribute on your `<a>`.

Comment: @Sean : That is currently no where like that, just an idea. See, the previous getElement, gets the `input type="text" id="searcher"` as `var seares = document.getElementById("searcher").value` and this is sent with `xhr.send(data);` by adding the seares variable to it.

The thing is, "searcher" is set already but a link generated by an php echo will generate a unique "value" to make the link so how do I use that `document.getElementById().value;` as the link data will always change. ... if that makes ANY sense

Answer (score 1):

You missed a single quote:

```
echo "<a id='",$row['compuid'],"' onlclick='soverlay();roverlay()' href='#'>",$row['compn']," | ",$row['compt']," </a>";
```

**My Solution**

You can add an attribute to the link with the number (*id*) of it. 
then with javascript on click on element  get it's attr. then pass it to the **ajax request** 
then on **display.php** get this *id* and do your query...

Comment: so this is my output the echo php writes :

`<a onclick="osearch();ocompdis();discomp()"></a>

<form>

    <input id="tester" type="text" hidden="hidden" value="abcdefg"></input>

</form>
<a onclick="osearch();ocompdis();discomp()"></a>

<form>

    <input id="tester" type="text" hidden="hidden" value="mnopqrs"></input>

</form>`

As you can see, id "tester" doesn't change. Please demonstrate with the above, how to get the link to make use of VALUE somehow to generate a unique link that can be grabbed or used by `document.getElementById().value` or something similar.

Comment: as in the above example, if I click on the first link, it will return id=tester, and display abcdefg. When I click on the other link, it will return id=tester again, and again display abcdefg. The id attribute , needs to be returned in some way, dynamically, that in the Javascript it will be unique and thus be able to display mnopqrs.